# Microsoft TFS 2010 - Branching and Merging

Tags: tfs

I need to branch and merge hundreds of files and the only way I know is to do it manually one by one.

Is there an automated way where I can just list all the file names with their path, add change set, and indicate the destination for it all to run by itself or better yet since the files have similar names (project id), an condition where it should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can branch and merge at the folder level. You do not need to branch and merge individual files, you can branch and merge a folder that contains all of the required files.